# Print a Webview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wan to print a webview.In android we can use WebViewClient & PrintManager to print a webview.[printing/html-docs](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs).
How can it done in flutter.

I tried this library [https://pub.dev/packages/printing](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs)

```
final pdf = pw.Document(version: PdfVersion.pdf_1_5, compress: true);

 final page1 = await Printing.convertHtml(
        format: PdfPageFormat.standard,
        html: '<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>',
      );
```

but how i can add page1 to the pdf ?
is this support css ?